# What to do if there are more variables than there are data points in Vector Autoregression?

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, vector-autoregression, small-sample

For vector autoregresive (1) model,

given the best estimated autoregressive parameter matrix $A$, and $Y$ is the data points matrix (variables by data points, say M by T) and $X$ is the 1 lagged data points of $Y$, then the best likelihood estimation for the covariance of the error, let $C$,using ordinary least squares method in matrix notation is 
$$ C = {1 \over {T-M-1}} (Y-AX)(Y-AX)^{T}$$

but what if $ M > T $ ? what if there are limited number of data points available but there are large variables?